# Post made in TinyMCE is not WYSIWYG

Tags: javascript, formatting, tinymce

I have included TinyMCE into my site.

The TinyMCE data gets stored in a column called "post" which is of type "Text" which is what it says to set the column type to in the manual.

When I display my posts on the front page of my site made in TinyMCE they do not look anything like what they were in the editor. Images and media are not displayed, formatting is gone, and the text is all one size.

Have I missed something out in the installation.

Here is a screenshot to of a post made in TinyMCE to show you what I mean.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y6koX.jpg

Thanks

Comment: look at the html that's going into the page. probably the `src` attributes in your `<img>` tags are wrong, because tinymce is in some other location than where the html is being displayed, leading to incorrect paths.

Comment: there's also a 'valid_elements' config file in tinyMCE that strips certain attributes depending on how it's set up (In the case I saw it would drop entire scripts)

Answer (score 0):

This may be subject to several things

- wrong tinymce init (valid_elements, valid_child_elements,...) leading to the undesired removal of html elements in the content (the tinymce cleanup performs)
- allowed attributes for elements not set correctly int he tinymce init leading to the undesired removal of html attributes in the content (the tinymce cleanup performs)